# Datagrid Selection: Consistency & Placement

Tags: interaction-design, design-patterns, tables, data-tables

I'm working on an application that heavily utilizes datagrids (unfortunately) and I question the placement of the select option. Refer to my attachment and the list below:

[image]

**Select Option - Datagrid**:

- I've allocated the first column for selection when the user needs to
  select or compare items. So far, so good.

**Select Option - Datagrid (2)**:

- Sometimes the user can select from a list of recipients and the same
  first column convention still makes sense. Great!

**Select Option In Datagrid**:

- In some instances the user needs to select from a list of packages
  (e.g., item 1, item 2, etc.) so they are applied to a location.
  Different from the first two examples, but for good reason.

**Select Option - Datagrid(2)**:

- A list of flights with data progressing in the order you would
  expect. As a result, the select option is the *last* column.

**Questions**

- Is Select Option In Datagird (2) breaking the convention set in the first two examples? Does the context justify the variation?
- If Select Option - Datagrid (2) and Select Option In Datagird (2) appeared within the same page, would the different selection orientations slow users down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the **Select Option in Datagrid(2)** reflects order for user task? My thoughts, user first chooses `Depart` and `Arive` (finally, the goal is to get from A to B?), then `Airline`. `Flight#` is a technical info which doesn't drive a decision.

Considering this you could re-order columns in `Select Option in Datagrid(2)` and for the consistency and familiarity locate the selection as the first column. This eliminates the second question, too.

[image]